# How to get the human readable content type name in a node template

Tags: theming, 8, nodes

I have created node template for my node, and its working fine.

I need to print content type name, which is like "Whitepaper" and has machine name "w1" in my node template. If I use variable `{{ node.bundle }}`, its printing the machine name. But **I need the human readable name**.

I tried many elements of node, content and page variables but I'm not able to print the human readable content type name.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should be able to get the human-readable name of the content type (or the "label") by using the following snippet in your node Twig template.

```
{{ node.type.entity.label }}
```

Comment: yes, this is the easiest solution, didn't cross my mind to use this field referencing the node type

Comment: I tried, {{ node.label }} which was returning machine name instead, {{ node.type.entity.label }} fulfilled my purpose, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You can add the human readable name of the content type in a preprocess hook:

*mytheme.theme*

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType;

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_node(array &$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $variables['content_type'] = NodeType::load($node->bundle())->label();
}
```

and use it in the node template:

```
{{ content_type }}
```